# Free memory from process space

Tags: c++

following is the code:

```
class x
{
    int k;
};
int main()
{
    x *p=new x[1000000];
    return 0;// can be  1 too
}
```

now question is when we come out of the main function the memory allocated is freed       by   compiler calling destructor or it is freed by the operating system as process will no longer exist.?

Comment: A note about the return value from `main`: Zero is considered "okay", while non-zero is considered an error return code.

Answer (score 3):

No destructors will be called but any decent operating system will reclaim all the resources of the defunct process. The standard however has no such requirements for implementations.

Comment: I think he knows that.  He's wondering if C++ will clean things up first.

Comment: possibly off topic: is there a way to delete comments on stack overflow?

Comment: @bchurchill move your mouse to the right of your comment. There should be an `x`.

Comment: @bchurchill Then the answer is "No."

Answer (score 1):

C++ won't free any memory unless you tell it too.  I'm not too familiar with how the exiting works in C++, but I'm pretty sure it's the operating system that's freeing all the memory here.  C++ might clean things up for you if you call the exit() function.

Answer (score 0):

As the developer, you should really take responsobility for this. Even better use a smart pointer. That aside, the operating sytstem should tidy up for you once the program is terminated. The c++ language itself will do nothing to reclaim the memory you allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Memory is not freed (by the compiler): no destructors will be called. Every `new` (or `new []`) must have a corresponding `delete` (or `delete []`): C++ let you to menage memory and you have to take care of this! By the way, when your program finish running, the OS reclaims resources (so memory used is freed by the system).

```
A* a = new A; 
delete a;
```

is interpreted by the compiler as

```
// assuming new throws std::bad_alloc upon failure
A* a = ::operator new(sizeof(A)); 
a->A::A();
if ( a != 0 ) {  // a check is necessary for delete
    a->~A(); // DESTRUCTOR IS CALLED BY THE DELETE OPERATOR
    ::operator delete(a);
}
```

(Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4795/C-Standard-Allocator-An-Introduction-and-Implement)